# XUnit test error : Cannot convert system.collections.generic.list <"filename.class"> to string

Tags: c#, methods, xunit

When I try to build a xunit test my expected is ok but I'm giving my actual variable the wrong thing. I'm learning xunit and this is driving me nuts at the moment.

My test for the method below :

```
    [Fact]
        public void AddToKartMethod()
        {
            var expected = "item";
            var actual = AddToKart.PutItemInKart("item", 3, 4.5);
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
```

My method :

```
  public static List<KartItem> PutItemInKart(string input, int inputNumber, double inputPrice)
        {
            List<KartItem> kart = new List<KartItem>();
            kart.Add(new KartItem() {
                Item = input,
                Pound = inputNumber,
                Cost = inputPrice
            });;
            return kart;
        }
```

My KartItem :

```
 public class KartItem
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public int Pound { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }

        public KartItem(string item, int pound, double cost)
        {
            item = Item;
            pound = Pound;
            cost = Cost;
        }

        public KartItem()
        {

        }
    }
```

In my test actual is underlined red and error message reads "Argument 2: Cannot convert from Systems.Collections.Generic.List to string. I want to test just the String Item from the PutItemInKart.

Comment: You are trying to compare two different types. Extract the desired value from the KartItem object to compare to expected value

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two different types. Extract the desired value from the KartItem object to compare to expected value

```
[Fact]
public void AddToKartMethod() {
    //Arrange
    string expected = "item";

    //Act
    List<KartItem> items = AddToKart.PutItemInKart(expected, 3, 4.5);
    string actual = items[0].Item;

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Note the explicit types used for the variables. This is a case where using `var` has cause confusion because the type is not known to the user/coder.

Do note however that the logic of that function should be reviewed. It will only always return a collection with one item since the list is created and populated in the function.